# Matrices multiplication in python without using numpy

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I've been trying to get this method ready for matrices multiplication. I'm using the `__mul__` special function for it.

This is the code i got so far:

```py
def verify_mul(self, other):  # only multiply when number of columns 1st == number of rows 2nd
        for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
            if len(self.matrix[i]) != len(other.matrix):
                print('Matrices cannot be multiplied')
                return False
        else:
            return True

    def __mul__(self, other):
        
        if not self.verify_mul(other):
            return

        p = len(self.matrix)
        for row in range(len(other.matrix)):
            q = len(other.matrix[row])
        for row in range(len(self.matrix)):
            n = len(self.matrix[row])

        m = Matrix(self.row, self.cols)

        for i in range(p):
            for j in range(q):
                for k in range(n):
                    m.matrix[i][j] = m.matrix[i][j] + self.matrix[i][k] * other.matrix[k][j]

        return m
```

It actually works fine, but the result matrix adds an additional row of zeros, and I don't know why.

This is how i tested it:

```py
m3 = Matrix(2, 3)
m4 = Matrix(3, 2)

for i in range(2):
    m3.matrix[i] = [5 for i in range(3)]

for j in range(3):
    m4.matrix[j] = [3 for i in range(2)]


print('the first matrix is:')
print(m3)

print('the second matrix is:')
print(m4)

print('the result is:')
print(m3 * m4)
```

And this is the result:

```
the first matrix is:
5 5 5 
5 5 5 

the second matrix is:
3 3 
3 3 
3 3 

the result is:
45 45 
45 45 
0 0
```

I'd like to know what's going on with that row of zeros because, besides that, the code is working fine.

**Thanks**

Comment: The function `verify_mul()` has no specified value when matrices have matching dimensions, so it will return `None` in such case. Then, since the boolean value of `None` is `False`,  `__mul__()` returns without computing anything.

Comment: should i add an ```else:```?

Comment: i changed the question!! pls check it out :)

Comment: Do you have your matrix class definition handy? If not, the declaration of matrix `m` with `m = Matrix(self.row, self.cols)` seems like it is only getting the dimensions of the new matrix from the what is defined under `self` (if I'm guessing correctly). It seems like you can just get the other dimension from the matrix `other` instead, and your extra (in this case) row is just coming from grabbing both dimensions from the same matrix. Ex. `m = Matrix(self.row, other.cols)`

Comment: In the listing `__mul__` is defined as inner function of `verify_mul`. Pleаse format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the method `__mul__` you are initializing the matrix as

```py
        m = Matrix(self.row, self.cols)
```

But the shape of the result should be `(p, q)`